# LINQ Include Values of children error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, subquery

I have this query:

```
var allValues = from p in _pContext.Persons
where p.Id == currentPerson.Id
from i in p.Items //This is a list that contains "Items"
select i;
```

I want to have all the Items and all the nested values that they contain. How do I load these when executing this query, too? I know theres the include statement that I can use on the context, but that doesnt lead anywhere. If I f.e. do this:

```
var allValues = from p in _pContext.Persons.Include("Items.Properties")
where p.Id == currentPerson.Id
from i in p.Items //This is a list that contains "Items"
select i;
```

to get all the items loaded with their associated "Properties", these properties arent loaded, their list is instanciated but it doesnt contains any.

Comment: A different version of the Include method does exist in a different class. That one accepts a lamda, where you specify the related object to include. As far as I know, you need to use: `using System.Data.Entity;` to be able to use.

Comment: do you have a one to many relationship between person and item?

Comment: Sorry I cant use the lambda expression because I'm using MySQL with EF which doesnt support the lambda expression for includes as far as i know.

Answer (score 2):

`Include` has lots of delusive quirks. One of them is that an `Include` is ignored if the query shape changes after it is applied. This happens in your case. The `Inlude` works if the query looks like this:

```
from p in _pContext.Persons.Include("Items.Properties")
select p
```

This is because the path `"Items.Properties"` is traversable off of the entity in the end result: `Person`.

But now you change the shape of the query by changing the returned entity...

```
from p in _pContext.Persons.Include("Items.Properties")
from i in p.Items
select i
```

... and the include path is no longer valid. (Not traversable off of `Item`).

For `Include` there's a simple rule of the thumb: apply it at the end of the query. Doing that, you'll automatically enter the correct path, esp. when you use lambda syntax:

```
(from p in _pContext.Persons
from i in p.Items
select i).Include("Properties")
```

or

```
(from p in _pContext.Persons
from i in p.Items
select i).Include(i => i.Properties)
```