# Nested Tables Using a DTO

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, nested, linq-to-entities

I need help getting my WebApi Controller to work.

I have a 3 table Models like this.

**First Table**

```
public class MainTable{ 
     public int MainTableID { get; set; }

     ...  Other Fields

     public ICollection<SubTable> SubTables { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Table**

```
public class SubTable{ 
     public int SubTableID { get; set; }

     ...  Other Fields

     public int MainTableID { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("MainTableID ")]
     [JsonIgnore]
     public virtual MainTable MainTable{ get; set; }

     public ICollection<SubSubTable> SubSubTables { get; set; }
}
```

**Third Table**

```
public class SubSubTable{ 
     public int SubSubTableID { get; set; }

     ...  Other Fields

     public int SubTableID { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("SubTableID")]
     [JsonIgnore]
     public virtual SubTable SubTable{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to flatten the first model because of other relationships not mentioned in this post so I am using a dto

**DTO**

```
    public class TableDTO
    {
         public int MainTableID { get; set; }

         ...  Other Fields (there is a lot of flattening happening here but I am going to skip it to keep this simple)

         public ICollection<SubTable> SubTables { get; set; }
    }
```

Now that I got all of that out of the way.  To my question..  I am linking this all to a web api controller.

If I use the DTO and create a controller like this

**Controller with DTO**

```
     public IQueryable<TableDTO> GetMainTable()
     {
          var mainTable = from b in db.MainTables
          .Include(b => b.SubTable.Select(e => e.SubSubTable))
                          select new TableDTO()
                          {
                              MainTableID = b.MainTableID 
                              eager mapping of all the fields,
                              SubTables = b.SubTables
                          };

          return mainTable;
     }
```

This works for everything except the SubSubTable which returns null.  If I ditch the DTO and create a controller like this

**Controller without DTO**

```
public IQueryable<MainTable> GetMainTable()
{
    return db.MainTables
        .Include(c => c.SubTables)
        .Include(c => c.SubTables.Select(b => b.SubSubTables));
}
```

This works perfect and the JSon returns everything I need, except that I lose the DTO which I desperately need for other aspects of my code.  I have rewritten my code in every way I can think of but nothing works.  I am pretty sure that this can be done with the DTO but I don't know what it would take to make it work, and as they say "You don't know what you don't know" so hopefully someone here knows.

Comment: You probably don't have lazy loading enabled. You could try eager load data like this `b.SubTable.Select(e => e.Include(x => x.SubSubTable))`.

Comment: Thank you @Pawel for your suggestion I thought I could go that way as well, but .Include isn't an avalible option. I can do `b.SubTable.Select(e => e.SubSubTable)` but it throws this error
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ServiceApplication.Models.SubSubTable>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ServiceApplication.Models.SubTable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   I have tried to get around it but I haven't found a way around it yet.

Answer (score 2):

In Entity Framework 6 (and lower), `Include` is always ignored when the query ends in a projection, because the `Include` path can't be applied to the end result. Stated differently, `Include` only works if it can be positioned [at the very end of the LINQ statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39897546/861716). (EF-core is more versatile).

This doesn't help you, because you explicitly want to return DTOs. One way to achieve this is to do the projection after you materialize the entities into memory:

```
var mainTable = from b in db.MainTables
      .Include(b => b.SubTable.Select(e => e.SubSubTable))
      .AsEnumerable()
                      select new MessageDTO()
                      {
                          MainTableID = b.MainTableID ,
                          // eager mapping of all the fields,
                          SubTables = b.SubTables
                      };
```

The phrase, "eager mapping of all the fields" suggests that the projection isn't going to narrow down the `SELECT` clause anyway, so it won't make much of a difference.

Another way could be to load all `SubSubTable` objects into the context that you know will be in the `MainTable`s you fetch from the database. EF will populate all `SubTable.SubSubTables` collections by *relationship fixup*.

Comment: I am trying to make your solution work but I am having a trouble.  Adding .AsEnumerable() in the current IQueryable call fails because it says can't convert a cast is needed.  I changed it to a IEnumerable call then it fails on load because "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first". I can leave the IEnumerable call and remove the .AsEnumerable() but then I am back to where I started with SubSubTables being null.  I will start googling relationship fixup to see if I can get that to work. Thank you for you help anymore advice?

Comment: What cast is needed? `AsEnumerable` should cast the `IQueryable` implicitly (it already *is* an `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Severity 
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ServiceApplication.ViewModel.MessageDTO>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ServiceApplication.ViewModel.MessageDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You changed your question. Where has `MessageDTO` gone? It's not clear where this error occurs. If `SubTables` in (now) `TableDTO` are of type `MessageDTO` then this all boils down to a simple AutoMapper job.

Comment: Correct.  I called it MessageDTO in one section of my original Comment and TableDTO in another section (as someone else's comment pointed out) so I renamed one of them to make it more consistent throughout, but you were already calling it MessageDTO so I just went with it in replying to you.  Sorry for the confusion.  I don't have AutoMapper implemented, and I would hate to have to add it just for this.  I feel like this shouldn't be as hard as it's been, is there not a way to map this manually?

Comment: OK, the question is: what is `TableDTO.SubTables`?

Comment: I have 3 models all with a one to many relationship.  MainTable -> SubTable -> SubSubTable  Using the controller with include and select I can get it to return the JSon I want.  The problem I am having is that I want to use a data transfer object on the MainTable (only) because it needs to be flatten for some fields.  That data transfer object is TableDTO and DTO's have to be mapped and I'm not using AutoMapper.

Comment: I don't have a problem manually mapping the first relationship SubTable, to TableDTO. It shows up but I lose the relationship between SubTable and SubSubTable.  Normally I would use .Include(c => c.SubTables.Select(b => b.SubSubTables)) Which doesn't work in this situation as we already know.  I am trying to find a way to make this work.  Maybe the answer is that I can't but it just seemed like something that should be possible. Does that clear my question up a little?

Comment: Oh, the return type can't be `IQueryable<TableDTO>`, it should be `IEnumerable<TableDTO>`.

Answer (score 0):

If  this works:

```
public IQueryable<MainTable> GetMainTable()
{
    return db.MainTables
        .Include(c => c.SubTables)
        .Include(c => c.SubTables.Select(b => b.SubSubTables));
}
```

Then use this one and just add a `Select()` to the end with a `ToList()`. Note the `IEnumerable` in the return type:

```
public IEnumerable<MainTableDto> GetMainTable()
{
     return db.MainTables
        .Include(c => c.SubTables)
        .Include(c => c.SubTables.Select(b => b.SubSubTables))
        .Select(c=> new MainTableDto { SubTables=c.SubTables /* map your properties here */ })
        .ToList();
}
```

Not sure about the types though (at one place you have `MainTableDto`,  at another you mention `MessageDto`?).

Comment: sorry it's the same it was EOD friday - typing corrected above.  SubSubTable still comes back null when I do this. Thank you for your help.  Any other suggestions?