# Does Include influence the performance of Count?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use C# Entity Framework and have the following Method to count my students

```
public static int GetStudentCount()
{
    using(SchoolContext ctx = new SchoolContext())
    {
        return  ctx.Student.Include("Subjects").Include("Subjects.SubjectsDescription").Include("Teacher").Count();
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a performance difference to this method?

```
public static int GetStudentCount()
{
    using(SchoolContext ctx = new SchoolContext())
    {
        return ctx.Student.Count();
    }
}
```

**Update:** Since some users are interested why adding the `Include()` at all - I want to reuse a Method with serval filters. So I have one method to get all students `GetStudent` and one method that uses the same code to filter the data and just returning a count (for database paging)

```
public static int GetStudentCount(Filter f)
{
   using(SchoolContext ctx = new SchoolContext())
   {
      return GetStudents(ctx.Student.AsQueryable(),f).Count(); // has filters an Include()
   }
}
```

Comment: Test it and see.

Comment: @GiladGreen it's hard to test since SQL has caching and I don't have enough data to notice a difference

Comment: @Toshi - The answer to does it influence is "yes" - adding includes creates joins. But the correct thing to do is just test - and for that - populating with data, executing query for a big amount of time and doing an average (or playing with DB properties for no caching if you can)

Comment: @Toshi I'd at least start by determining if there is any difference in the SQL that's created.  If the Includes do create a query with a bunch of Left Joins then not having them would definitely be more efficient.

Comment: You can inspect the generated SQL, that will give a first hint.

Comment: https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof can be useful for seeing what queries are actually executing.

Comment: `Count` query falls into *ignored includes* category, hence should not affect the query performance.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was wondering if EF was smart enough to do that.  Good to know.

Comment: @juharr At least the latest EF 6.1.3

Comment: There's a simple [rule of the thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39897546/861716) for Include. Although in ef-core the behavior is more versatile. I should add that to this Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Test the difference i execute the code below and log the generate query against my oracle database.

```
var context = new DbContext();
context.Database.Log = Log;
var count = context.TBCO_CATEGORY.Count();
```

the generate query was

```
SELECT 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "A1"
    FROM "SIMS"."TBCO_CATEGORY" "Extent1"
)  "GroupBy1"
```

then i execute the following code

```
var context = new SIMSContext();
context.Database.Log = Log;
var count = context.TBCO_CATEGORY.Include(x=>x.TBCO_ITEM).Count();
```

the generate SQL was:

```
SELECT 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "A1"
    FROM "SIMS"."TBCO_CATEGORY" "Extent1"
)  "GroupBy1"
```

which mean same SQL statement so same execution plan.